# Restify & Bluebird - how to pass an error from a catch block to restify error handler?

Tags: javascript, promise, bluebird, restify

I am working on a node js server, and using bluebird for promise implementation. I understand how to use promises, but my problem is what to do with the error returned from a promise. I tried the simple solution - just trowing the error again - but bluebird catch it, and the client never receive a response. Bellow is a demo code, to illustrate my question:

```
var restify = require('restify');
var Promise = require('bluebird');

var server = restify.createServer({
  name: 'myapp',
  version: '1.0.0'
});

server.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
    new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        reject(new Error());
    }).then(function(res){
        res.send('hello');
    }).catch(function(e){
        throw e;
    });
});

server.on('uncaughtException', function (req, res, route, error) {
    console.log('error');
});

server.listen(7070, function () {
  console.log('%s listening at %s', server.name, server.url);
});
```

I am looking for a way to somehow pass the error to restify, so it will raise the `uncaughtException` event and I could handle it like any other uncaught exception. After searching this a bit, I found that I can simply do something like `next(new InternalServerError())` and restify will raise an event for this specific error, but this is look a bit weird to me, so I am looking for a better way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a PoC that will rethrow any "possibly unhandled rejections". These will subsequently trigger Restify's `uncaughtException` event:

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');
var restify = require('restify');
var server  = restify.createServer();

server.listen(3000);

Promise.onPossiblyUnhandledRejection(function(err) {
  throw err;
});

server.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
  Promise.reject(new Error('xxx')); // no `.catch()` needed
});

server.on('uncaughtException', function (req, res, route, err) {
  console.log('uncaught error', err);
  return res.send(500, 'foo');
});
```

Comment: Thank you! this is look like what I wanted.

Comment: ok, this is only working if the error has no message in it - as restify render the response (using the error message) and then call the after event handler. This make all this solution a bit irrelevant for me...

Comment: I tried to run it on my machine, and it seems like the exception is not caught by restify domain. I add `process.on('uncaughtException',` and it caught the exception, but this is not much of help as I can't return something to the client. I will try to look later if I can find a way to use restify domain.

Comment: @omer fwiw, I'm using `restify@4.0.0`, `bluebird@2.9.34` and `node@0.12.7`

Comment: So it might be my restify version, I just now noticed I am using outdated restify (3.0.3). I will check latter, but if it work for you, this is probably the solution.